# UDID of users who made inApp Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I need to get UDIDs of devices on which inApps from my app were made. Is it possible from iTunes connect or thru any API for developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple will not give you this information. The way they provide is to retrieve previous transactions made by the user on the current iTunes account. Apple would very much not like it if you were trying to limit the validity of the purchases to the devices not the user. You could have some analytics (flurry, google...) that keeps tracks this information but it is not usual practice, you should not attempt to identify individual users when building statistics on your app's usage.

Comment: +1 for correct answer and to enhance the issue, you should under no circumstances (even if possible using Google Analytics, Flurry, Omniture,...) collect a plain UDID but use a hashed version instead to prevent legal issues in some countries (privacy protection violation).

Comment: Thanks a lot, just to clarify my issue - some of my apps were hacked and now I'm looking for a way to protect them in future, not to collect users info just for statistics. Main trouble is to find out was app installed from Appstore or was downloaded from torrents to a jailbroken device.